# Getline skips last semicolon (csv) c++

Tags: c++, arrays, csv, vector, getline

I have a really big csv file with 10 comma seperated values in each line, at the end of each line is a \n.

Now I have a row with just semicolons. The amount of values corresponds to how many comma seperated values are in the other lines

```
5696;Neusser Strasse;49;1;50670;Neustadt-Nord;18.09.1990;um;1890;Wohn- u. Geschäftshaus
;;;;;;;;;
5698;Richard-Wagner-Strasse;18;1;50674;Neustadt-Süd;18.09.1990;;1905;Wohnhaus
```

When I now start to run my program, it gets the "5698" from the 3rd line as the last value of the 2nd line, so what I get is this:

```
0 Denkmalnummer: 5696
1 Strasse: Neusser Strasse
2 Nummer: 49
3 Bezirk: 1
4 PLZ: 50670
5 Ort: Neustadt-Nord
6 unter Schutz: 18.09.1990
7 Baujahr Zusatz: um
8 Baujahr: 1890
9 Kurzbezeichnung: Wohn- u. Gesch├ñftshaus

****************

0 Denkmalnummer: 
1 Strasse: 
2 Nummer: 
3 Bezirk: 
4 PLZ: 
5 Ort: 
6 unter Schutz: 
7 Baujahr Zusatz: 
8 Baujahr: 
9 Kurzbezeichnung: 5698

****************
0 Denkmalnummer: Richard-Wagner-Strasse
1 Strasse: 18
2 Nummer: 1
3 Bezirk: 50674
4 PLZ: Neustadt-S├╝d
5 Ort: 18.09.1990
6 unter Schutz: 
7 Baujahr Zusatz: 1905
8 Baujahr: Wohnhaus
9 Kurzbezeichnung: 5699
```

This continues and messes up the proper alignment of the data.

My major code looks like this (via getline the file's data is stored in a vector):

```
if (denkmallist.is_open()) {
    if (counter < 1) {
        while (getline(denkmallist, line)) {
            stringstream ss(line);
            while (getline(ss, line, ';')) {
                ausgelesenes.push_back(line);
                counter++;
                daten.push_back(ausgelesenes);
                ausgelesenes.clear();
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        while (getline(denkmallist, line)){
            ausgelesenes.push_back(line);
        }
        daten.push_back(ausgelesenes);
        ausgelesenes.clear();
    }
}
```

and the code which then displays the results looks like this:

```
for(int x=0, y=semis; x<=semi2+2, y<daten.size(); x++, y++){
        if (x > semi2-1){
            x = 0;
            cout << '\n' << "****************" << '\n' << endl;
        }
        cout << x << " " << daten[x][0] << ": " << daten[y][0] << endl;
    }
```

Semi represents the amount of entires.

I would be very happy if someone could help me out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inner loop uses the call to `getline` to decide when it has finished parsing the text string that was read by the outer call to `getline`. That's okay, but you have to watch out for extraneous failures.

For the first line, the inner loop runs ten times; once for each field that ends with a `;` and once more to read the remaining text.

For the second line, there is no text after the last `;`. After the ninth time through the loop, `getline` sees no text and no delimiter, so it concludes that it's at the end of the input. The call fails, and the inner loop exits after reading only nine inputs instead of the expected ten.

Comment: Okay, thanks very much! But how can I then add \n as a delimiter or isn't that possible?

Comment: @CorneliusDiefenthal -- this is just one example of ill-formed input data. The code as written assumes that all of the input is properly formed. A robust program would have checks for validity. Fixing this particular one won't solve the general problem. At the least, it should check how many fields have been read when the inner loop exits. If it's less than ten, something went wrong.

Comment: Okay, then I'll try to put a counter in it, thank you.

Comment: In the case where a line ends at the 9th `;` with no subsequent text, `line` will be blank (`getline()` is required to clear it before attempting to read it), so if blank then simply test if the stream is at EOF and not in a failed state, and if so then process `line`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you, I'll try to code that, sounds logical

Comment: Found my solution; I just checked if a line ends with a `;`. If so, I added another `;`. Not the best way to do it but it works for me.